# how to create routes and import components dynamically from a json file in angular2 rc5

Tags: angular

i am trying to creates routes dynamically from a static json file which i am reading from a XHR request also i am try to import component which are also written on the same json file. I am trying to figure out how we can use the json data in our routes configurations.

The first obvious challenge i'm facing is how I can get the json data and implement in our config before initialising the angular app. Secondly, even if I manage to get the json data to our configuration, how can I declare them in our module.js file, or rather add to our declaration.

Would be glad if anyone can help. If source code needed please let me know.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason you would want/need to do this...

Comment: Well, this is I need as well, for my cms based ng2 app.

Answer (score 1):

With ng2 RC5 intruduced NgModule it is possible now

here is @NgModule config:

```
import { routing }        from './app.routing';
@NgModule({
   imports:      [ BrowserModule,HttpModule,JsonpModule, routing ],
   declarations: [ AppComponent ],
   bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is components loading, you can see name of components is from a string array that can be read from Json file from your database or disk.

```
const routes: Routes= GetScreens();
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

function GetScreens(){
  var results :Array<Object> = Array<Object>();
  let screens :Array<string> = ["page1","page2","page3"]

  results.push({ path: '' ,redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'});
  results.push({ path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module'       })
  screens.map(screenId => results.push({path: screenId, loadChildren:   'app/screens/' + screenId + '.module' }))
 return results 
}
```

Say here : { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module'} we load component "welcome" from file app/screens/welcome.module.ts, without import {}.

Pls check full story/detail code here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/nm5m7N?p=preview